# How to list a Chrome App in the Store's Offline Enabled Category?

Tags: google-chrome-app

How to take a [Chrome packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps) that works offline and have it listed in the Chrome Web Store's [Offline Enabled](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/collection/offline_enabled) Collection?

Answer (score 1):

While most app listing attributes are controlled from the [Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard), the bit to flip to indicate that it works offline is done in the [app manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) file! Set [`offline_enabled`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/offline_enabled) to true:

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  // ...
  "offline_enabled": true,
  // ...
}
```